# React: SetState of Functional Component from Within a Callback

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-hooks

My top level functional component `App` has a Promise-returning function `req()` that will be called from many child components. Internally, `req()` updates `App`'s state to display that it was called (and why), then calls a different promise-returning function. Here is `req()`:

```
  //wrap all requests to track and display their progress
  function req(func, args, waitCap, yayCap) {
    
    //perform a callback on a given req, then update state
    const withReq = (argId, callback) => {
      let newReqs = state.reqList.map ( r => r); //copy the reqList

      for (let reqIndex = 0; reqIndex < newReqs.length; reqIndex++) { //iterate through the list
        if ((newReqs[reqIndex] && (newReqs[reqIndex].id === argId))) {  //find a match
          callback(newReqs[reqIndex]);  //pass it to the callback
          break;
        }
      }

      setState( prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        reqList:newReqs,
      }));
    }

    //kill a req and update state
    const deleteReq = argId => {
      let newReqs = state.reqList.filter( r => {  //new reqList is the same list with no objects containing the argID
        return r.id !== argId;
      });

      setState( prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        reqList:newReqs,
      }));
    }

    //duplicate the req list
    let newReqs = state.reqList.map( r => r );

    const now = new Date(); //create a unique ID for this req for tracking
    const reqId = [
      now.getFullYear(),
      String(now.getMonth()+1).padStart(2,"0"),
      String(now.getDate()).padStart(2,"0"),
      String(now.getHours()).padStart(2,"0"),
      String(now.getMinutes()).padStart(2,"0"),
      String(now.getSeconds()).padStart(2,"0"),
      String(Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)).padStart(4,"0"),
    ].join("");

    newReqs.push({  //add the new req to the new reqList
      status:"waiting",
      caption:waitCap,
      id:reqId,
    });

    setState( prevState => ({ //render the changed list of Reqs
      ...prevState,
      reqList:newReqs,
    }));

    return ServerCalls[func](args)
    .then((res)=>{        
      withReq(reqId, foundReq =>{ //update the req to show success
        foundReq.status="success";
        foundReq.caption=yayCap;
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        deleteReq(reqId); //remove it from display after 3 seconds
      }, 3000);
      return res;
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      withReq(reqId, foundReq =>{ //update the req to show failure
        foundReq.status="failure";
        foundReq.caption=foundReq.caption+" Failed!";
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        deleteReq(reqId); //remove it from display after 3 seconds
      }, 3000);
      throw err;
    })
  }
```

The problem here is that the callback functions in `Promise.then()` and `Promise.catch()` operate on state's initial value and not the value it has when the callback executes, due to scoping. This isn't a problem with class components, just functional ones.

Is there a way for a functional component to read its execution-time state from within a callback? Or is a workaround required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems here:

- You're mutating the existing state when you do

```
withReq(reqId, foundReq => { //update the req to show success
    foundReq.status = "success";
    foundReq.caption = yayCap;
});
```

Never mutate state in React - it can cause re-rendering problems.

- The value in the `.then` callback is stale. Fix this by passing to `callback` the *current (newly updated) state* in a state setter function, instead of the old state:

```
const withReq = (argId, callback) => {
    setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        reqList: prevState.reqList.map(req => (
            req.id === argId ? callback(req) : req
        )),
    }));
}
```

Then make sure `callback` doesn't mutate, but creates and returns a new object instead, eg:

```
withReq(reqId, foundReq => ({
    ...foundReq,
    status: "success",
    caption: yayCap,
}));
```

Comment: After making all your listed changes, the desired behavior is achieved. However, before I mark this as the correct answer, could you clarify the state mutation you pointed out? I believe that in the function I posted, no state is mutated. The callback passed to `withReq` would be performing its actions on an element of the newly created `newReqs` array. Doesn't that fix the issue?

Comment: The array is new, but the objects are the same. You aren't deep cloning the array, only creating a new container that the same objects exist in. It's like `const obj = {}; arr1.push(obj); arr2.push(obj); obj.foo = 'bar'`